# How can I set default values for SafeConfigParser?

Tags: python, data-structures, default, default-value, configparser

I have a config file as follows:

```
[job]
mailto=bob
logFile=blahDeBlah.txt
```

I want to read the options using `SafeConfigParser`:

```
values = {} 
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
try:
    config.read(configFile)
    jobSection = 'job'

    values['mailto'] = config.get( jobSection, 'mailto' )
    values['logFile'] = config.get( jobSection, 'logFile' )
    # it is not there
    values['nothingThere'] = config.get( jobSection, 'nothingThere' )
.... # rest of code
```

The last line of course will throw an error.  How can I specify a default value for the `config.get()` method?

Then again, if I have an options file as follows:

```
[job1]
mailto=bob
logFile=blahDeBlah.txt

[job2]
mailto=bob
logFile=blahDeBlah.txt
```

There seems to be no way to specify default options for `job1` different from the default options in section `job2`.

Comment: These are actually two separate questions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can also use a default ".ini" file and read it before your actual config file.

default.ini:

```
[job1]
mailto=jack
logfile=default.log

[job2]
mailto=john
logfile=default.log
```

config.ini:

```
[job1]
mailto=sparrow
logfile=blah.log

[job2]
logfile=blah2.log
```

parsing:

```
import ConfigParser  # For Python 3 use the configparser module instead (all lowercase)

config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.read('default.ini')
config.read('config.ini')

print config.get('job1', 'mailto')
# -> sparrow (from config.ini)

print config.get('job1', 'logfile')
# -> blah.log (from config.ini)

print config.get('job2', 'mailto')
# -> john (from default.ini)

print config.get('job2', 'logfile')
# -> blah2.log (from config.ini)
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer to the OP question

Comment: @Luke101 it's kind of awkward when distributing a package though. You have to distribute the default.ini in the package data and jump through some hoops to read it back when you need it.

Comment: @Ben Farmer - In that case you can embed your default ini inside the program as a multiline string and replace `config.read('default.ini')` with `config.read_string(mydefaultstring)`

Answer (score 23):

Use the `defaults` parameter to the constructor:

```
# class ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser([defaults[, dict_type]]) 
#
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser({'nothingThere': 'lalalalala'})
...
...
# If the job section has no "nothingThere", "lalalalala" will be returned
# 
config.get(jobSection, 'nothingThere')
```

Comment: Todah, I was confused that there seems to be no way to specify the [section] name for the default.  I'll try it today.

Comment: I do not understand how this answers the question. What if defaults should be different for job1 and job2?

Comment: This won't actually work because "nothingThere" automatically gets lowercased to "nothingthere".  If you want option names to be case-sensitive you need to do config.optionxform=str, then config.set('DEFAULT', 'nothingThere', 'lalalalala')

Answer (score 20):

In Python 3 you can provide a fallback value to the get() method as follows:

```
values['nothingThere'] = config.get('job', 'nothingThere', fallback=0)
print(values['nothingThere'])
# -> 0
```

Comment: The default value is already provided by the second argument, and I have never seen a `fallback` argument. Can you point to some documentation?

Comment: Note that this is the parser-level get method, not the section's get method, hence the second argument is the key, not a default value. Documentation here - https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#fallback-values

Comment: @MadPhysicist It depends how you use the ConfigParser. You can either call it with `config["my_section"].get("my_option", "fallback_value")` (and here, indeed the second argument "fallback_value" will be the default value) or with `config.get("my_section", "my_option", fallback="fallback_value")` (and here the two first arguments are to specify which option of which section you want to get)

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the  [DEFAULT] section to set default values for the properties you haven't defined in any other section(s).

E.g.

```
[DEFAULT]
checkout_root: /data/workspace

[pingpong]
name: Ping Pong App
checkout_root: /home/pingpong
src: %(checkout_root)s/src

[dingdong]
name: Ding Dong App
src: %(checkout_root)s/dingdong_src
```

For the ding ding app, the value of `src` will be `/data/workspace/dingdong_src`

Comment: This answer is the answer to the second question of OP.